# Laravel request is an array but not recognized by count()

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am passing an array into my controller via axios.post request. I am trying to get the length of the $request array that I am passing to the controller. However, I keep recieving a "Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable" error.

Here is what my array looks like:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'text' => 'It is this',
    'question_id' => 98,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'text' => 'And it is that',
    'question_id' => 98,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'text' => 'Also a little bit of this',
    'question_id' => 98,
  ),
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
$count = sizeof($request));

$count = $request->length;

$count = count($request);
```

The only thing that has had even a little bit of success is doing:

```
$count = count($request[0])
```

This returns 2, which is for the elements inside the first array. It counts text, and question_id. While this is good progress this is not what I want

What I would like to see happen is to have the length of the entire $request object. In the example I gave above, I would like to either receive 2, (the end of 0,1,2) or 3 (the count of 0,1,2).

Comment: what do you get if you do: `var_dump(get_class($request))`? Maybe `$request` is not an array. You can also try `var_dump(gettype($request))` for checking if the variable its really an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `$request` is an `Illuminate\Http\Request`, it won't be directly countable.

You can count `$request->all()` or `$request->input()`, though.

Comment: In as much as this will count the number of items in the requests, it will not count the number of items in a single request say C

Comment: If you are sure that C is an array and C is part of the request then doing count($request->C) not e that count here is a regular PHP function

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
count($request->all());
```

Answer (score 0):

In as much as the accepted answer will count the number of items in the requests, it will not count the number of items in a single request request item say C. If you are sure that C is an array and C is part of the request then doing `count($request->C)` not e that count here is a regular PHP function

Answer (score 0):

try ;

`count($request->all());`

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.